# Bash command to do multiple things in a server in command line

Tags: linux, bash

I am having a problem doing what I need. I can save a ton of time if I do this right.

I basically need to loop over every host, and I can get that part on my own.

But I can never get the command to come out right.

I basically want to do this for every host

```
 chmod 750 /root; chown -R root:root /root;exit;
```

I've tried so many variants and all of them them will just `ssh` to the server and do nothing on that server. They never actually run that command on the destination server. Instead they end up running the command on the server I am running `ssh` from.

Also note public keys are already set up so passwords are no issue.

So to give a better understanding I will show this

```
for h in HOSTNAMES do
  ssh $h; OTHER STUFF
done
```

Comment: Are you chaining your "connect to server" command with this using a &?

Comment: Have you tried `chmod 750 /root && chown -R root:root /root`?

Comment: You're not actually showing how you ssh into your servers and execute these commands, though that probably is the problem, here

Comment: how are you managing entering the password for `root`? I think that has to be the number 1 problem. But we need to see some failed code to help fix it, we can't write it for you ;-) OK? Good luck.

Comment: secure equivs is already set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to the remote server is given as the final argument to `ssh`. Also the `exit` command is not required, as the connection is closed after commands are completed.

```
for h in $HOSTNAMES
do
  ssh $h "chmod 750 /root; chown -R root:root /root"
done
```

Comment: Yeah I was just wanting to make sure the exit was done... I'll try this when I can later.

Comment: This definitely worked. Thanks. I had to modify a few things on my end because of how we can do something but yeah this was great.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me.

```
C02NQ9GLG3QD:~ lcerezo$ ssh -K myhost "last -1;uptime"
lcerezo   pts/2        172.31.0.40      Wed Dec 16 17:31 - 17:39  (00:07)
wtmp begins Tue Sep  8 17:15:21 2015
16:12  up 1 day,  5:06, 6 users, load averages: 2.16 1.98 2.00
C02NQ9GLG3QD:~ lcerezo$`
```

Have you looked at tools like pdsh?
For mass configuration though, I think your time will be better spent learning a configuration management tool such as:

- ansible
- puppet
- cfengine
- salt stack

Comment: That might work but not in this instance. I don't have that ability.

Comment: Which ability? the -K flag is my usage, but not relevant to the question. the important part is to put these in quotes.